# How many DML statements will be execute?

Tags: apex, dml

Given the code below, and assuming there are 500 accounts in the system, how many DML statements will be executed?

```
for (List<Account> accounts : [SELECT Id, Name]) 
{ 
    update Accounts; 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

0 - Your code will error as the SOQL is not valid, when fixed:

Only 3 DML statement(s) will be used and 500 dml rows will be used

each batch of 200 will count as 1 DML statement

```
for(Account[] a : [Select ID From Account Limit 500])
    update a;
```

> 14:05:24.588 (11588787877)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
>   Number of 
>   SOQL queries: 1 out of 100
>   Number of query rows: 500 out of 50000
>   Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20   Number of DML statements: 3 out of 150

From the [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm):

> For Apex saved using Salesforce.com API version 20.0 or earlier, if an
>   API call causes a trigger to fire, the chunk of 200 records to process
>   is further split into chunks of 100 records. For Apex saved using
>   Salesforce.com API version 21.0 and later, no further splits of API
>   chunks occur. Note that static variable values are reset between API
>   batches, but governor limits are not. Do not use static variables to
>   track state information between API batches.

A more syntactically correct way to do this would be:

```
database.update([Select ID, Name From Account]);
```

although its only purpose would be to execute triggers and code associated with an update.

Conversely, this will use 500 DML statements (obviously it will error at the limit) and should **not** be used in this way (only for illustration)

```
for (Account a : [SELECT Id, Name]) 
{ 
    update a; 
}
```

Comment: i know that its only one DML statement will be used but i was taking a mock-up dev 501 exam and the correct answer is `3 DML statement` and I have no idea why its say 3 so I thought to post the question.... here

Comment: Because the trigger executes in groups of 200 so it would be 3...Answer updated

Comment: oh so each will have 200 rows at a time?

Comment: @AbuHamzah - Yes. Answer update. Give me a minute and I will post logs to show it

Comment: okay got it, i was thinking that it does in one batch (whatever the records it contains) but  it only does 200 rows in a group...

Comment: @AbuHamzah - Right (it chunks them in groups of 200). You have to keep this in mind when doing development as if you have say 5 DML statements that get executed in a transaction, when you update in bulk (say limit of 10K) you will have 250 DML statements and thus will hit limits. This needs to be taken into considertaion for not only DML but Query rows SOQL statements, etc. Hence the need to always use best practices across all your codebase